# Prevent \topinsert on chapter page (Plain TeX)

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, output-routine

How to define chapter to prevent insertion of floating figures and tables (`\topinsert`) on chapter page. I would like to place an object at the top of the next page.

```
\def\chap#1{\vfil\break \vglue1cm
  {\nobreak\noindent #1\par}
  \nobreak\bigskip\firstnoindent}  

\chap Name of chapter

Some text

\topinsert
some table or figure
\endinsert
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a check in `\pagecontents` that we're not in a chapter starting page. You need that your chapter has more than one page, though.

```
\newif\ifchapterpage

\def\chap#1\par{%
  \vfil\break\vglue1cm
  {\nobreak\noindent #1\par}
  \global\chapterpagetrue
  \global\dimen\topins=0pt % no topinserts in the chapter pages
  \nobreak\bigskip
  %\firstnoindent % commented because definition is missing
}

\catcode`@=11
\def\pagecontents{%
  \ifvoid\topins
  \else
    %\unvbox\topins % this is what Plain TeX does
    \ifchapterpage
      \global\dimen\topins=\maxdimen % restore the default
    \else
      \unvbox\topins
    \fi
  \fi
  \dimen@=\dp\@cclv \unvbox\@cclv % open up \box255
  \ifvoid\footins
  \else % footnote info is present
    \vskip\skip\footins
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\footins
  \fi
  \ifr@ggedbottom \kern-\dimen@ \vfil \fi
  \global\chapterpagefalse % let's reset the conditional at shipout time
}
\catcode`@=12

\chap Name of chapter

Some text

\topinsert

\leaders\hbox{\strut some table or figure}\vskip6\baselineskip

\endinsert

Some other text

\vfill\eject

Some other text on the next page

\bye
```

Comment: This does not work, because first page is underfull and second page is overfull. You can try to insert normal text to your example.

Answer (score 3):

There is much more simple solution:

```
\def\chap#1\par{%
  \vfil\break\vglue1cm
  {\nobreak\noindent\bf #1\par}
  \global\dimen\topins=0pt
  \nobreak\bigskip
}
\output=\expandafter{\the\output \global\dimen\topins=\vsize}
```

Or using OPmac:

```
\input opmac

\addto\chaphook{\global\dimen\topins=0pt }
\addto\endoutput{\global\dimen\topins=\vsize}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a simple way to prevent more than one top-insertion per page?

Comment: I forgot to say "using OPmac"

Comment: I tried with `\addto\endinsert{\global\dimen\topins=0pt}`.  It gives good results only if there are not too many insertions

Comment: @User I am unable to imagine your problem. Give a source text with an example.

Comment: Don't worry, I've already solved it by myself.  Thank you anyway :)